# Docker build python app error "No matching distribution found for spacy==2.3.2" on Apple M1

Tags: python, node.js, docker, spacy, apple-m1

I recently switched to a Mac mini M1, and am trying to run a project that was running ok in my old intel MBP. Because the project uses node@10, I switched to using Rosetta2, but even with Rosetta2, one of the docker builds still errors.

The failing `Dockerfile` (omitted some lines for brevity)

```
FROM python:3.8

ADD requirements.txt /

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

`requirements.txt` (omitted some packages/lines that I thought were unrelated)

```text
blis==0.4.1
spacy==2.3.2
```

When trying to build this with docker-compose, I get (omitted some stack-trace & formatted for readability):

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

    /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize;
    sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-a0pf23u9/blis_b27be89cc1164feb9077684e8666c831/setup.py'"'"';
    __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-a0pf23u9/blis_b27be89cc1164feb9077684e8666c831/setup.py'"'"';
    f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);
    code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');
    f.close();

    exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install
        --record /tmp/pip-record-5h72yjx8/install-record.txt
        --single-version-externally-managed
        --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-84ng6en9/overlay
        --compile
        --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-84ng6en9/overlay/include/python3.8/blis

    Check the logs for full command output.

#9 113.4   WARNING: You are using pip version 21.0.1; however, version 21.1 is available.
#9 113.4   You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
#9 113.4   ----------------------------------------
#9 113.4 WARNING:
    Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/18/db/499f374339b522b6618234b93f25d2990692795ccce3152519ccc508586c/spacy-2.3.2.tar.gz#sha256=818de26e0e383f64ccbe3db185574920de05923d8deac8bbb12113b9e33cee1f
    (from https://pypi.org/simple/spacy/) (requires-python:!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*,!=3.4.*,>=2.7).
    Command errored out with exit status 1:

        /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install
            --ignore-installed
            --no-user
            --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-84ng6en9/overlay
            --no-warn-script-location
            --no-binary :none:
            --only-binary :none:
            -i https://pypi.org/simple
            -- setuptools wheel 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=3.0.2,<3.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.4.1
            
    Check the logs for full command output.

#9 113.4 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement spacy==2.3.2
#9 113.4 ERROR: No matching distribution found for spacy==2.3.2
```

Before the `Run pip install ...` line, I tried adding:

- `RUN pip install pip --upgrade`, failed,
- `RUN pip install wheel`, failed,
- `RUN pip install spacy==2.3.2 --no-cache-dir` (commented out `spacy` in `requirements.txt`), failed,
- all of the above at the same time, failed.

Any idea what could be wrong, or what the solution may be here?

---

UPDATE:
Tried to build the above `Dockerfile` (initial version) in a terminal using `arm64`, but still get the same error.

---

UPDATE 2:
Tried bumping (minor) `blis` & `spacy` packages, still fails with the same error.

Comment: spaCy 2.3.2 is pretty old and predates the release of the M1 chips, so there's no build for it. You could build it from source but you're better off using a more recent version (as you seem to have figured out). I think 2.3.5 will work but if not try v3, though note there are breaking changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also tried it with 2.3.5, but that gave the same error. Despite the breaking changes, had to bump it to 3 as you said, and it worked ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a last resort, I bumped all the packages in the requirements file to their latest versions, and now it builds successfully.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Not sure *when* we can start using M1s and need to make sure all the tools we use will work (e.g. spacy).